# Django 1.4: No wrapping of exceptions in TEMPLATE_DEBUG mode hides exceptions

Tags: django, django-templates

I've asked on the django-users mailing list but haven't got any answer .. so I guess I'll try here.

> In previous versions of Django, whenever the TEMPLATE_DEBUG setting was True, any exception raised during template rendering (even exceptions unrelated to template syntax) were wrapped in TemplateSyntaxError and re-raised. This was done in order to provide detailed template source location information in the debug 500 page.
>
> In Django 1.4, exceptions are no longer wrapped. Instead, the original exception is annotated with the source information. This means that catching exceptions from template rendering is now consistent regardless of the value of TEMPLATE_DEBUG, and there's no need to catch and unwrap TemplateSyntaxError in order to catch other errors.

Pretty cool .. I guess. But now how can I see raised exceptions ?

If I include a template or call a template tags which raise an
exception, nothing happen.

I appreciate the added robustness.. but without clear documentation on
how to show those exception, debugging is a bit painful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question, but I'll have a go answering it.

When `DEBUG` and `TEMPLATE_DEBUG` are `True`, and an exception is raised during rendering, you see the (very familiar to this Django developer) yellow error page.

With Django 1.3 and earlier, Django would report a `TemplateSyntaxError`

> #### TemplateSyntaxError at /my-url/
>
> **Caught ValueError while rendering: This is the exception value**
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/my-url/
>   Django Version: 1.3.1
>   Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
>   Exception Value: Caught ValueError while rendering: This is the exception value

As of Django 1.4, you see the original exception instead:

> #### ValueError at /my-url/
>
> **This is the exception value**
>   Request Method:   GET
>   Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/my-url/
>   Django Version:   1.4
>   Exception Type:   ValueError
>   Exception Value:  This is the exception value

To test this yourself, try raising an exception in any template tag that you include in your template:

```
raise ValueError("This is the exception value")
```

Or an even easier way to see the difference is to use the url tag with an invalid view name.

```
{% url invalid_view_name %}
```